# Parsing/expanding escaped array in Stream Job?

Tags: user-defined-functions, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, cross-apply, azure-analysis-services

I'm using an Azure Stream Job to parse incoming JSON data from an IoT Hub.
I'm even using ...

```
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(event.NestedRows) as nestedrows
```

... to expand and denormalize additional events within each event - works great, no issues.

However, I have a new JSON property that is of type **string** and it is actually an embedded JSON array. For example:

```
{ 
    "escapedArray": "[ 1, 2, 3 ]" 
}
```

I'd like to use CROSS APPLY on this array as well, however I don't see any way to parse the string and convert it to a JSON array.

I considered a User Defined Function (UDF), but I read that it can only return scalers, and not arrays.

Is there a trick I'm missing inside the Stream Job to parse this string, or do I have to expand it in the event stream, prior to the Stream Job?

(FYI, I have no way to change this stream in the device event source.)

-John

Answer (score 0):

According to the offical [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions), you can create an UDF in Stream Analytics to convert a string to an array.

Defined an UDF `udf.toJson` as below.

```
function main(arrStr) {
    return JSON.parse(arrStr);
}
```

Then use the UDF in a Query for the property `escapedArray` to return an array.

```
SELECT
    UDF.toJson(escapedArray) as uarr
INTO
    [YourOutputAlias]
FROM
    [YourInputAlias]
```

My test result is as the figure below.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks very much Peter, I'll try that in the morning and let you know how I do.

Comment: Here is the link where I read that UDF's can only return scalars (not arrays). [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions) _JavaScript user-defined functions support stateless, compute-only scalar functions that do not require external connectivity. The return value of a function can only be a scalar (single) value. After you add a JavaScript user-defined function to a job, you can use the function anywhere in the query, like a built-in scalar function._

Comment: Also, I tried creating a UDF as you suggested, unfortunately I hit a blocker. Apparently the **CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(UDF.toJson(event.readings) ) as reading** does not know the UDF returns an array, and issues a compile error, claiming that GetArrayElements needs an array. I also tried casting it **CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(CAST(UDF.toJson(event.readings) as array)) as reading**